# How to prove that this linear operator is nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an arbitrary matrix , $\mathbb{C}$ is complex fields, and $L$ a mapping that is defined by

$L:M_n(\mathbb{C})\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $L(X):=AX+XA$. How can we show that $A$ is nilpotent iff $L$ be nilpotent?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Is nilpotent here of order $k$ or do you define just for $k=2$?

Comment: it sounds k=2 Icompute $L^i$ for i=1,2,3,4 but why for i greater than 2 is not nilpotent?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is your definition of nilpotent?

Comment: i know definition of nilpotent($\exists k \in N $  {$A^k=0$}  but my qustion is why nilpotently order is not K≥3

Comment: It can happen that $k\ge 3$, it doesn't have to be $k=2$.

Comment: Note that what is nilpotent here is the linear operator $L$, not the matrix $L(X)$. So, I have changed the title from "*How to prove this matrix is nilpotent*" to "*How to prove that this* ***linear operator*** *is nilpotent*" to avoid confusion.

Comment: i mean $\exists k\in N$ s.t$ A^k=0$ iff $\exists d\in N  \quad s.t \quad $L(X)^d $ =0 $ [$(AX+XA)^d =0$]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, show that for $i=1,2,\ldots$, there exist some *positive* integers $c_{i0},\ldots,c_{ii}$ such that $L^i(X) = \sum_{j=0}^i c_{ij} A^j X A^{i-j}$.

Now, if $A^k=0$, show that $L^{2k-1}=0$.

Conversely, if $L^i=0$ for some natural number $i$, by considering $L^i(A)$, show that $A^{i+1}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

- Look at L(A)
- Look at LL(X), LLL(X), and maybe LLLL(X).

Comment: Is it useful here that the $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is an PI ring?

Comment: you mean  let $A^k=0$  and compute $L^i(x)$ to find nilpotently order of L and vice versa

Comment: @Maisam: Yep; once you've looked at them, that's the next idea to have. I tried to keep the hint minimal both for the sake of being a hint to give you the chance to make the connections, and to emphasize the phase of problem solving where you are still finding leads to explore without actually knowing where they're going to lead yet.